# Databricks readStream in batch job multiple source matched and attempted to modify the same target row

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I am using two layers in an ETL process, the bronze one and the silver one.

In the bronze layer we are using the spark.readStream command and read the bronze table, so we are getting just the new data, and we have the .trigger(availableNow=True) so we are not letting the stream to ramain alive, we execute the process every day as it were a batch job.

Here it is the problem, when there is an error in the silver notebook, in the next execution the silver layer will need to process the new data and the data from the previous batch so if we have duplicated primary keys then we get the error from the title of the question, as we have two options available in source for the same record in the target table.

I have tried two things, order the df (spark.readStream) with the incremental column and then make a groupby with the primary keys columns (and all the others columns as fisrt() agg), the problem the you cannot orderby in the spark.readstream:

```
bronzeDF= (spark.readStream
              .format("delta")
              .table(source_table))
              .orderBy(col(incr_column).desc())
aggregation_columns = [first(col(c)).alias(c) for c in bronzeDF.columns if c not in columnskeys_list ]
group_columns = [col(col_name) for col_name in columnskeys_list]
bronzeDF = bronzeDF.groupBy(*group_columns).agg(*aggregation_columns)
```

The second option was to make a windows function:

```
window_spec = Window.partitionBy(*columnskeys_list).orderBy(desc(incr_column))

bronzeDF = bronzeDF.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(window_spec))

bronzeDF = bronzeDF.filter("rn = 1")
```

Here I got that you cannot window function without a time window.

I know that my main problem is that I am thinking the dataframe as a statical data and it is not. I am letting the whole code:

```
columnskeys_list = columnskeys_str.split(",")
        
        bronzeDF= (spark.readStream
              .format("delta")
              .table(source_table))
              #.orderBy(col(incr_column).desc())
              
        #window_spec = Window.partitionBy(*columnskeys_list).orderBy(desc(incr_column))

        #bronzeDF = bronzeDF.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(window_spec))

        #bronzeDF = bronzeDF.filter("rn = 1")
        aggregation_columns = [first(col(c)).alias(c) for c in bronzeDF.columns if c not in columnskeys_list and c != incr_column ]
        aggregation_columns.append(max(col(incr_column)).alias(incr_column))
        group_columns = [col(col_name) for col_name in columnskeys_list]
        bronzeDF = bronzeDF.groupBy(*group_columns).agg(*aggregation_columns)


def upsertToDelta(microBatchOutputDF, batchId, target_table, condition):
  microBatchOutputDF.createOrReplaceTempView("updates")

  microBatchOutputDF.sparkSession.sql(f"""
    MERGE INTO {target_table}
    USING updates
    ON {condition}
    WHEN MATCHED
      THEN UPDATE SET *
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
      THEN INSERT *
  """)

def bronzeToSilver(target_table, condition, checkpoint):
  if spark.catalog.tableExists(target_table):
    (
      bronzeDF
      .na.fill(0).na.fill('')
      .writeStream
      .format("delta")
      .foreachBatch(lambda df, batchId: upsertToDelta(df, batchId, target_table, condition))
      .trigger(availableNow=True)
      .outputMode("complete")
      .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint)
      .start().awaitTermination()
    )
  else:
    (
      bronzeDF
      .na.fill(0).na.fill('')
      .writeStream.format("delta")
      .outputMode("complete")
      .trigger(availableNow=True)
      .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint)
      .toTable(target_table)
      .awaitTermination()
    )
```

I know that my main problem is that I am thinking the dataframe as a statical data and it is not